# HTML Integrated Help

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, adminform

Has anyone see a way to integrate a html help system into magento admin?

For example, on a admin page, include a button which links to a context sensitive help file

I know there are a few links in admin which point back to magento wiki pages, however I wanted to build my own integrated help files

thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too hard. Your biggest problem is organizing those help files (I presume they're web pages) for a contextual match. You could create a new entity with attributes like "locale", "content", "frontname", "controller", "action" - the last three being used for contextual priorities, the most specific URL part ("action") having the top priority.
Then a grid/edit for CRUD operation on them, a special controller for rendering them etc.

Mind you, the above is just a blunt suggestion.

---

As for the original link...

That link is rendered here: [github link](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/menu.phtml#L33).

You must rewrite [this adminhtml helper method](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php#L65) in order for you to get a different URL. You can easily make it point to your custom admin controller, your blog (?) etc.

Just try to keep the help contextual, as you can see in the helper method.

---

Kudos for creating custom help files. It's rare to see this approach and it's a refreshing dedication to the customer.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your thoughts, its given me a few ideas on how to move forward. The plan is to write this inside magento. That way the help files are part of the module itself. No external links, but perhaps options to handle it.

Im surprised its not been done before, most of the extension I buy come with a pdf, which seem crazy way to provide documentation. Especially if the module of for an end users.

So its cool, i'll have a play round with writing something which is flexible enough to be used across the admin site

cheers